# validating the mobile numbers

Tags: .net, regex, validation, expression

I need a regular expression to validate the mobile number up to 9 digits, if the telephone number starts with 8 otherwise 10 digits needs to be entered. The numbers must start either with 9 or 8 with above criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(8\d{8}|[1-79]\d{9})$
```

Comment: your expression is also accepting numbers statring with 1 ,2,3 ..so on. I need numbers starting with 8 or 9 with the above condition

Comment: No, it behaves exactly as you specified.

Comment: @skamale You didn't say anything special about numbers starting with 9. This regex matches only nine digit strings starting with 8 and ten digit strings starting with numbers other than 0 and 8. If that's not what you want, edit the question's wording to clarify it. Add a couple of examples of what should and should not be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the answer, but you should check out this very useful website for reg expressions incase you are interested:

http://www.regexlib.com

http://www.regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression to match the phone numbers starting with 8 or 9.

```
^8|9(8\d{8}|[1-79]\d{9})$
```